# Why does the 90th percentile come out to be greater than the greatest number?

Tags: statistics, percentile

Why is the 90th percentile of the following numbers 0.193204884?
0.193111065
0.188885706
0.191501273
0.193298704
0.18895934
0.192364606
How can the 90th percentile be greater than the greatest number in the set?
I used the formula - =PERCENTILE(R:R,0.9) on excel. [R:R is the excel range which contains the following numbers]

However, the 90th perentile of 1,2,3,4,5 comes out to be 4.6 which seems correct.

Comment: $0.193298704$ is greater than $0.193204884$.

Comment: Thank you. Facepalm. I assumed that the numbers were in an ascending order without even looking at them. Have I always been this stupid or have I become stupid in the last couple of years?

Comment: My brain has atrophied. My job very rarely requires me to think. It's just busywork.

Comment: @navneesi: Maybe you need a different job!

Comment: New job or not, you should be aware that different texts and software programs use slightly different definitions of quantiles. For large samples, these differences are unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

Comment continued. R statistical software allows you to choose from among several different definitions of quantile, all widely used. [[See documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.1/topics/quantile).]

```
set.seed(1119)
x = sort(round(rnorm(11, 50, 5)))
x
[1] 42 43 46 47 48 51 52 52 53 55 59
```

Here are results for *quartiles* using several different `type`s.

```
quantile(x, type=4)
   0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
42.00 45.25 49.50 52.25 59.00 

quantile(x, type=5)
   0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
42.00 46.25 51.00 52.75 59.00 

quantile(x, type=6)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
  42   46   51   53   59
```

The idea is that some compromises are required when trying to partition
eleven values into four appropriate groups; also the presence of ties
can complicate finding quantiles. There is no universal agreement
how best to do this.  R uses type 7 as it's default.

```
quantile(x)  # if type unspecified, you get type 7
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
42.0 46.5 51.0 52.5 59.0
```

So don't be surprised of you encounter discrepancies between a textbook
definition and a particular type of software.